# GIT, .gitignore and file tracking

Tags: git, version-control

guys. I am having an issue with my git stuff. Story goes like this:
I had a file which I didn't want to add to commits - `a.file`
Before my first commit I added 'a.file' into my `.gitignore`
Now I deleted `a.file` after several commits
Question is:
 If I take of 'a.file' from `.gitignore`, won't it appear in my .git (I mean memory issue, won't it suddenly, start to be tracked and take space, after I deleted it during the time it was in `.gitignore`)

Comment: No. If you find it in future, it could be added by others.

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

No, even you remove `a.file` from `.gitignore`, the `a.file` won't be tracked or take any space in `.git`.

- Before you deleted `a.file` in your git repo, the file was not tracked by git since it's specified in `.gitignore`. In another word, it didn't take space in .git folder.
- After you deleted the `a.file` from working directory now, the file also not tracked by git since it's not exist.

So even you remove the content `a.file` from `.gitignore` file, the file won't show in your commit history.

Answer (score 0):

No, Git won't track this file.

The official [gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) says the following:

> "A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore. Files already tracked by Git are not affected"

This means that while you had `a.file` in your `.gitignore`, it was not tracked by Git. Now that `a.file` is deleted, there is no way for Git to suddenly start tracking it.